# Entity Framework Code First Casting Columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have an class

```
public class Foo
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm using the code first fluent mapping to map this to the database.

```
Property(i => i.UserId)
            .HasColumnName("userno");
```

the only problem is that userno is actually a char(10) in the database. How do I go about casting or converting this type? as I currently get this error.

> The 'UserId' property on 'Foo' could not be set to a 'String' value.
>   You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't have any support for type conversion in mapping so the only valid mapped property in your scenario is:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

If you want `int` property as well you must do:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int UserIntId 
    {
       get { return Int32.Parse(UserId); }
       set { UserId = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

And add this to your mapping:

```
Ignore(i => i.UserIntId);
```

You can play with accessibility of `UserId` property but be aware that accessibility also affects if your mapping actually sees the property. If it doesn't you will not have `UserId` mapped at all.

Comment: Figured this might be the case :(