# Stored Procedure sometimes returns short, sometimes returns int

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I'm working with a legacy codebase and need to call a stored procedure that **I'm not allowed to modify**. This stored procedure returns a row or multiple rows of validation data.

Example of result set (two columns, code and text):

```
0 "success"
```

OR

```
3 "short error"
4 "detailed error"
```

In the procedure itself, the message is selected simply as:

```
Select 0 as code, 'success' as text
```

**Problem:**

I'm using Entity Framework to map the result of this stored procedure to a custom class:

```
public class ValidationResult
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

The call itself:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ValidationResult>(@"old_sproc").ToList();
```

I've written some integration tests, and have noticed that when the procedure returns the success message, the 0 comes across as a `short`.  When it returns a non-zero message, it comes across as an `int`. I assumed that setting `code` as an int, the short would fit in. Unfortunately, I get the following exception for my success test:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int16' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.

When I switch `code` to a short to make my success test pass, my failure test fails with the following exception:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int16' type is not valid.

ADO.NET is **an** answer

One solution is to fall back to ADO.NET's `SqlDataReader` object, so I have that as a fallback solution. I'm wondering if there is something I can do on the EF side to get this working, though.

Comment: Does changing the `code` property to a `short` solve the problem?

Comment: It breaks the failure case.  So it makes success work, but when an error returns, it comes in as an int, resulting in a cast exception just in reverse.

Comment: Can you add a property so that you have a short and an int, and then assign based on type that you get in result?

Comment: The EF mapping logic requires the property be named exactly the same as the column that is returned from the sproc.  So, it would have to be named short code and int code, and that obviously won't compile (not that I didn't try!).

Comment: IMO `SqlDataReader` is the better answer. Not only will it give you the flexibility you need it will run quicker too. The code isn't all that difficult once you get started. If there are any stored procedures that return multiple result sets this would be a good experience leading up to those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This is a follow-up to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29283914/240733). It is only relevant for [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) and later.)

### Short answer:

```
var sql = "EXECUTE old_sproc WITH RESULT SETS ((code INT, text VARCHAR(MAX)))";
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ValidationResult(sql).ToList();
```

### Approach taken in this answer:

This answer will follow in your footsteps and use `SqlQuery` to execute your stored procedure. (Why not an altogether different approach? Because there might not be any alternative. I'll go into this further below.)

Let's start with an observation about your current code:

> ```
> var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ValidationResult>(@"old_sproc").ToList();
> ```

The query text `"old_sproc"` is really abbreviated T-SQL for `"EXECUTE old_sproc"`. I am mentioning this because it's easy to think that `SqlQuery` somehow treats the name of a stored procedure specially; but no, this is actually a regular T-SQL statement.

In this answer, we will modify your current SQL only a tiny bit.

### Implicit type conversions with the `WITH RESULT SETS` clause:

So let's stay with what you're already doing: `EXECUTE` the stored procedure via `SqlQuery`. Starting with SQL Server 2012, the [`EXECUTE` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) supports an optional clause called **`WITH RESULT SETS`** that allows you to specify what result sets you expect to get back. SQL Server will attempt to perform implicit type conversions if the actual result sets do not match that specification.

In your case, you might do this:

```
var sql = "EXECUTE old_sproc WITH RESULT SETS ((code INT, text VARCHAR(MAX)))";
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ValidationResult(sql).ToList();
```

The added clause states that you expect to get back one result set having a `code INT` and a `text VARCHAR(MAX)` column. The important bit is `code INT`: If the stored procedure happens to produce `SMALLINT` values for `code`, SQL Server will perform the conversion to `INT` for you.

Implicit conversions could take you even further: For example, you could specify `code` as `VARCHAR(…)` or even `NUMERIC(…)` (and change your C# properties to `string` or `decimal`, respectively).

If you're using Entity Framework's `SqlQuery` method, it's unlikely to get any neater than that.

For quick reference, here are some quotes from the linked-to MSDN reference page:

> *"The actual result set being returned during execution can differ from the result defined using the WITH RESULT SETS clause in one of the following ways: number of result sets, number of columns, column name, nullability, **and data type**."*
>
> *"If the data types differ, an implicit conversion to the defined data type is performed."*

### Do I have to write a SQL query? Isn't there another (more ORM) way?

None that I am aware of.

Entity Framework has been evolving in a "Code First" direction in the recent past (it's at version 6 at this time of writing), and that trend is likely to continue.

The book "Programming Entity Framework Code First" by Julie Lerman & Rowan Miller (published in 2012 by O'Reilly) has a short chapter "Working with Stored Procedures", which contains two code examples; both of which use `SqlQuery` to map a stored procedure's result set.

I guess that if these two EF experts do not show another way of mapping stored procedures, then perhaps EF currently does not offer any alternative to `SqlQuery`.

(P.S.: Admittedly the OP's main problem is not stored procedures per se; it's making EF perform an automatic type conversion. Even then, I am not aware of another way than the one shown here.)

Comment: Ingenious.  Just tried this and it works like a charm.  Barring something else that fixes it via C#, this is the winner.

Comment: even with cast(x as int) in my final SELECT of an sp, it started returning values as decimal (or so .NET thinks so all of a sudden) and WITH RESULT SET was the only cure...

Answer (score 5):

If you can't alter the stored procedure itself, you could create a wrapper stored procedure which alters the data in some way, and have EF call that.

Not ideal of course, but may be an option.

Comment: This is definitely an option, but it feels more hacky than just using old-school ADO.NET to get the result.  I've got it working using ADO.NET, but I'm still interested in seeing if there is a solution for EF.

Comment: You make a great point--the DB in question has over 1500 stored procs, so adding another one is ill-advised.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

(**Note:** If you're working with SQL Server 2012 or later, see [my follow-up answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29290343/240733), which shows a much shorter, neater way of doing the same thing described here.)

Here's a solution that stays in EF land and does not require any database schema changes.

Since you can pass any valid SQL to the `SqlQuery` method, nothing stops you from passing it a multi-statement script that:

1. `DECLARE`s a temporary table;
2. `EXECUTE`s the stored procedure and `INSERT`s its result into the temporary table;
3. `SELECT`s the final result from that temporary table.

The last step is where you can apply any further post-processing, such as a type conversion.

```
const string sql = @"DECLARE @temp TABLE ([code] INT, [text] VARCHAR(MAX));
                     INSERT INTO @temp EXECUTE [old_sproc];
                     SELECT CONVERT(INT, [code]) AS [code], [text] FROM @temp;";
                     //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^
                     // this conversion might not actually be necessary
                     // since @temp.code is already declared INT, i.e.
                     // SQL Server might already have coerced SMALLINT
                     // values to INT values during the INSERT.

var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<ValidationResult>(sql).ToList();
```

Comment: Along the same lines as above, this feels a little hacky, and ADO.NET works.  Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @GarrisonNeely: If you're not totally against using `SqlQuery`, check out [my new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29290343/240733). Same idea, better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity framework data modeler page (`Model Browser`), either change the *functional* mapping to a specific int which works for the `ValidationResult` class or create a new *functional mapping* result class which has the appropriate int and use that as the resulting DTO class.

I leave this process a touch vague because I do not have access to the actual database; instead I provide the process to either create a new functional mapping or modify an existing one. Trial and error will help you overcome the incorrect functional mapping.

---

Another trick to have EF generate the right information is temporarily drop the stored proc and have a new one return a *stub* select such as:

```
select  1 AS Code , 'Text' as text

RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

The reasoning for this is that sometimes EF can't determine what the stored procedure ultimately returns. If that is the case, temporarily creating the *stub* return and generating EF from it provides a clear picture for the mappings. Then returning the sproc to its original code after an update sometimes does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Ignore the int/short. the text is always the same for the same number right? get just the text. have a switch case. Yes its a hack but unless you can fix the root of the problem (and you say you are not allowed) then you should go with the hack that will take the least amount of time to create and will not cause problems down the road for the next person maintaining the code. if this stored proc is legacy it will not have any new kinds of results in the future. and this solution together with a nice comment solves this and lets you go back to creating value somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

Cast the static message code to an int:

```
Select cast(0 as int) as code, 'success' as text
```

This ensures the literal returned is consistent with the int returned by the other query.  Leave the `ValidationResult.code` declared as an `int`.

Note: I know I missed the part in the question about the SP can't be modified, but given that this makes the answer quite complicated, **I'm leaving this here for others who may have the same problem, but are able to solve it much more easily by modifying the SP.**  This does work if you have a return type inconsistency in the SP and modifying is an option.

Comment: I believe that's not an option, given the "stored procedure that I'm not allowed to modify" bit in the question.

Comment: Correct.  I'm not allowed to modify the stored proc.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely Have you tried setting your code property to type `string`?  This would allow you to create another proeprty to proxy the value to/from int/string using TryParse.  I'm not sure it will allow this but worth a shot.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely Unfortunately there's not a builtin way to specify type conversion for EF AFAIK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6909569/84206

Comment: I actually tried the string route hoping it would be converted but got a similar exception saying that the string to int16 conversion was invalid.

Answer (score -3):

There is a workaround you could use if you don't find a better solution. Let it be an int. It will work for all error codes. If you get an exception you know the result was a success so you can add a try/catch for that specific exception. It's not pretty and depending on how much this runs it might impact performance.

Another idea, have you tried changing the type of `code` to `object`?

Comment: When reading again I realized it returns many rows. If you might get many rows in the "success" case this won't work.

Comment: And it is obviously an abuse of exception handling. There *must* be a better alternative.

Comment: "Exceptional" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064332/asp-net-performance-which-is-faster/18064433#18064433) code is never a good idea.  I did try the `code` as an object and it failed, returning null in both cases.

Comment: Yes, and I wrote that in the answer too. But considering you are making a db call I bet you won't even notice the exception. Ofcourse it depends on the server. But that DB call would cost ~5-50ms in most cases. The exception would probably cost 0.05-0.1ms. Ofcourse it costs some memory too as it put the data on the stack.  

If you are calling this code in a loop I would certainly not use an exception. But I wouldn't call the DB in a loop either.